# mysql time(3) convert to seconds with milliseconds

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble figuring this out and could use some ideas. I have a `time(3)` field the stores a time example `00:01:06.765` . I need to convert this time to seconds with the milliseconds.  I am aware of `TIME_TO_SEC()` but that only gives me 66 sec in this case and what i need is 66.765 . Any Ideas?